# Ajax request support Android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, android-jsinterface

Is Ajax Request supported in android(4.0 +). If so please provide some help. I need to call ajax from android WebView using javascript.

Comment: as far as I know it is not supported, you might need to work with Jquery

Comment: @Jithu what do you want to do exactly? What kind of ajax request you want to do from WebView? Why can't you use just usual request from android without WebView to same host?

Comment: @gulliver007 Could you please give more details on working with Jquery. I have used Jquery ajax, but the response was not "success".

Answer (score 0):

I think, It is the problem with 4.0.x to 4.1.0